# Best wording for adding gas to a solution

Tags: word-choice

I am currently writing the experimental section for a thesis in chemistry. Someone, who did the reaction I want to describe, wrote: "the gas was bubbled into the reaction mixture at such a rate that almost no excess gas was detected." However, to me, the wording rather seems like lab slang.

The following is a list of what I found

- *the gas was passed into the solution* ([Link](https://www.dict.cc/?s=einleiten)) I have never heard anyone say this and I don't really like it, but if this is right, I will have to accept it.
- *the gas was introduced to/into* (which?) *the solution*
- *the gas was injected into the solution*

For a better understanding of what I am aiming for: The gas was added so slowly, that the bubbles hardly ever reached the surface before being absorbed/dissolved. So the pressure was quite low.

So, what would best describe the slow addition of a gas to a solution?

Comment: The first word I thought of was [infuse](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/infuse) but I'm not sure if it is the best choice for this context.

Comment: *Infuse* looks pretty good.  It occurs in a lot of contexts like ["The Technology is a unique method of infusing gas into liquids..."](http://inventures.ca/gasinfusion.html)

Comment: To me, *infused* feels more like it is used in connection with liquids being infused. But I guess it could work.

Comment: If you use gas being passed, you'll have a hard time getting your advisor to take your thesis seriously. (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pass_gas)

Comment: @mathewb Yes, I know. I was afraid of that. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gas can be **[introduced](https://books.google.com/books?id=6yTv29OIXLsC&pg=PT357&dq=%22introduced%20into%20the%20liquid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo3NKT9PfWAhVC6CYKHSXmChsQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=%22introduced%20into%20the%20liquid%22&f=false)** into a liquid or into a container of some kind.